# required PHP file sometimes animates differently

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css-animations

Ok, so basically after successful (or not) database injection I require some php file.
It's a pretty basic animation. Just a "tick" or "X" animation saying if it went ok.
However the problem is, sometimes it animates differently.
Wanted effect is both appearing and dissapearing animation.
And my "tick" or "X" either work good or there's no "appearing" animation, tick/X are just on the screen  from very beggining and then they will disappear.

**CSS (if needed):**

```
<style>

.circ{
    opacity: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 130;
    stroke-dashoffset: 130;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -ms-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.tick{
    stroke-dasharray: 50;
    stroke-dashoffset: 50;
    -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s 1s ease-out;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s 1s ease-out;
}
.drawn + svg .path{
    opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;

}
#tick1{
    padding-left: 2vh;
    height: 18vh;
    width: 18vh;
}

#komunikat {
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 22vh;
    width: 22vh;
    display: block;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

#tekst {
    font-size: 2vh;
    line-height: 2vh;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2vh;
    width: 18vh;
    margin-left: 2vh;
}

</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="komunikat">
<div id="tick1">
<div id="trigger"></div>
<svg version="1.1" id="tick" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 37 37" style="enable-background:new 0 0 37 37;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="circ path" style="fill:none;stroke:#0f0;stroke-width:3;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="
    M30.5,6.5L30.5,6.5c6.6,6.6,6.6,17.4,0,24l0,0c-6.6,6.6-17.4,6.6-24,0l0,0c-6.6-6.6-6.6-17.4,0-24l0,0C13.1-0.2,23.9-0.2,30.5,6.5z"
    />
    <polyline class="tick path" style="fill:none;stroke:#0f0;stroke-width:3;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;" points="
    11.6,20 15.9,24.2 26.4,13.8 "/>
</svg>
</div>
<div id="tekst">Urządzenie Wypożyczone</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
document.getElementById("trigger").classList.add("drawn");
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("trigger").classList.remove("drawn");
    document.getElementById("komunikat").style.visibility = "hidden";
},3000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that you do:

```
document.getElementById("komunikat").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

But you never set it back to `"visible"`.

To demo:

```js
document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("trigger").classList.add("drawn");
  document.getElementById("komunikat").style.visibility = "visible";
  setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("trigger").classList.remove("drawn");
      document.getElementById("komunikat").style.visibility = "hidden";
  },3000)
});
```

```css
.circ{
    opacity: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 130;
    stroke-dashoffset: 130;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -ms-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.tick{
    stroke-dasharray: 50;
    stroke-dashoffset: 50;
    -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s 1s ease-out;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s 1s ease-out;
}
.drawn + svg .path{
    opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;

}
#tick1{
    padding-left: 2vh;
    height: 18vh;
    width: 18vh;
}

#komunikat {
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 22vh;
    width: 22vh;
    display: block;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

#tekst {
    font-size: 2vh;
    line-height: 2vh;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2vh;
    width: 18vh;
    margin-left: 2vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="komunikat">
<div id="tick1">
<div id="trigger"></div>
<svg version="1.1" id="tick" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 37 37" style="enable-background:new 0 0 37 37;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="circ path" style="fill:none;stroke:#0f0;stroke-width:3;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="
    M30.5,6.5L30.5,6.5c6.6,6.6,6.6,17.4,0,24l0,0c-6.6,6.6-17.4,6.6-24,0l0,0c-6.6-6.6-6.6-17.4,0-24l0,0C13.1-0.2,23.9-0.2,30.5,6.5z"
    />
    <polyline class="tick path" style="fill:none;stroke:#0f0;stroke-width:3;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;" points="
    11.6,20 15.9,24.2 26.4,13.8 "/>
</svg>
</div>
<div id="tekst">Urządzenie Wypożyczone</div>
</div>


<button id="click">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't clarify. When the query is over, $_SESSION variable is set and page redirects to itself. Then page checks if the variable is set, based on it's value it requires the above PHP file and unsets the php variable. So making it visible again shouldn't be a thing.

Comment: Ah.  Where do you include the JavaScript? Sounds like you need to wait for the page to load before the js runs, try wrapping your code in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {`

Comment: Sadly it didn't help

Comment: All this (CSS, JS an HTML) is one PHP file in this order if it matters